# Untiy Shader Variant Collection

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, variant

1、Why did I click the clear button,currently tracked doesn't clear. How to re-collect shader variants for project.

2、How to collect shader variants automaticlly by script?

[image]

Comment: I don't see the point of wanting to collect them, why would you want to do this ?

Comment: When game start, use shadervariantcollection warmup shaders.

Answer (score 0):

1、In order to solve this problem, I clear the shaderCache files in project's Library folder.
2、I made a new Scene with a Quad, load all mat add to the quad in turn, last save the asset, but this would strip the variant by script Enabled Keys.